# How to dynamically pivot table by month and display top 10 by total amount for the whole year only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, pivot

I have a dynamic dataset that returns data from today and a year back. 
How can I pivot this data and return only top 10 `Description` by `NetWrittenPremium`?

I know how to perform static pivot, but confused how would I do it in this case.

```
        ;with cte_TopClasses
    AS  ( 
            SELECT      
                        b.MonthNum,
                        b.YearNum,
                        GovClassCode + ' - ' + dda.GovClassDesc as Description,
                        ISNULL(SUM(Premium),0) as NetWrittenPremium 
            FROM        tblCalendar b 
            LEFT JOIN   ProductionReportMetrics prm ON b.YearNum = Year(prm.EffectiveDate) AND b.MonthNum=Month(prm.EffectiveDate) AND  CompanyLine = 'Arch Insurance Company'
            LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[Dynamic_Data_ArchWC] dda ON prm.QuoteGUID = dda.QuoteGuid    
            WHERE       
                        ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
                        ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) )      
            GROUP BY    b.YearNum ,
                        b.MonthNum, 
                        GovClassCode,   
                        dda.GovClassDesc
        )
   --here I want to pivot it
    select *
    from cte_TopClasses
```

Current result is 128 records.

[image]

And desirable result would be something like that:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to pivot in the SQL, let the report handle the grouping. The whole point of tables in SSRS is that the grouping is inherently dynamic. To get the top 10 you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function in the SQL or use the `RowNumber` function in SSRS.

Comment: Could you please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085189/how-to-display-top-10-based-on-total-amount-in-ssrs-2012

Answer (score 0):

Hmm depends on a number of things what is best solution.

If every description has the same number of months you can do something like:

```
SELECT TOP 12 * @NumberOfDescriptionsToReturn
    MonthNum
    , YearNum
    , Description
    , NetWrittenPremium 
    , SUM(NetWrittenPremium) OVER (PARTITION BY Description) Total
FROM #T1
ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

Then in SSRS, set your RowGroup to Description and set ColumnGroup to your Months (I don't believe you need a `PIVOT` from your current table to the required report).  You can also use the total in the query as your total column.

If they don't have all the dates, you can force them to by doing a `CROSS JOIN` on your distinct dates to a distinct table of descriptions and then left join the rest of your tables.