# How to display top 10 based on total amount in SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

[image]

I need to display only top 10  `Class` based on `Total` `(SUM(Premium))` column. 
I go to group ClassCode properties --> Filters and setting top 10 by SUM(NetWrittenPremium) but it doesnt work.

I need to display only top 10 and also the total amount should be for only those 10.

Cant understand how to achieve it.

[image]

[image]

here is my query:

```
;WITH cte_TopClasses
AS  ( 
SELECT

        c.YearNum,
        c.MonthNum,
        DD.ClassCode,
        ISNULL(SUM(prm.Premium),0) as NetWrittenPremium 

FROM    tblCalendar c
LEFT JOIN  ProductionReportMetrics prm ON c.YearNum = YEAR(prm.EffectiveDate) and c.MonthNum = MONTH(prm.EffectiveDate) 
           AND CompanyGUID = '18E04C99-D796-4CFA-B1E7-28328321C8AD'      
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Dynamic_Data_GLUnitedSpecialty] DD on prm.QuoteGUID = DD.QuoteGuid 
WHERE   ( c.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and c.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
        ( c.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and c.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) ) 
GROUP BY    c.YearNum,
            c.MonthNum,
            DD.ClassCode--,prm.Premium

    )
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClassCode ORDER BY NetWrittenPremium DESC),*
FROM cte_TopClasses
```

and my outcome from the query:

[image]

@Alan
Thanks. 
Query output look like that:

[image]

If I add ClassCode in `order by` in `dense_rank`  then $142,000 is not gonna be in a query. Which is not good.

Any other ideas? Maybe I can use `partition` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Group Properties add a sort and set

```
Sort by expression "=Sum(NetWrittenPremium)"
Order = "Z to A"
```

Them in the filter as follows:

```
Expression = "=Sum(NetWrittenPremium)"
Operator = Top N
Value = 10
```

**Actually I've just noticed the Total row....** This will not calculate the total correctly and you cannot use aggregations in filters on the tablix (which would have worked otherwise).

You best bet would be to push this back to the server and do it there.

I can't test this on your data directly but it should work, I tested on someting similar...

```
SELECT r.* FROM 
    (SELECT d.* 
            , dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY TotalNWP Desc) AS rnk
        FROM 
            (SELECT DISTINCT
                ClassCode, YearNum, MonthNum
                , SUM(t.NetWrittenPremium) OVER (PARTITION BY ClassCode, YearNum, MonthNum) AS NetWrittenPremium
                , SUM(t.NetWrittenPremium) OVER (PARTITION BY ClassCode) AS TotalNWP
             FROM cte_TopClasses t
            ) d
    ) r
    WHERE rnk <=10
```

Now there should be no need to do any filtering in SSRS, just sorting by the `rnk` column.

You only remaining problem is how to determine which of the last results (which all have the same total) take precedent over the others. You could do something like adding ClassCode to the dense_rank function to the are chosen alphabetically but that;s for yo to decide I guess.

Comment: Alan thanks. But thats how I've been doing it. It still generates me 11 rows with total for 11 rows.

Comment: Do you have 2 Totals with the same value? Anyway. I noticed that the Totals will not work by filtering within the group so I'm updating the answer (5 - 10 mins)