# How to get a total sum for each Description and order it in dynamic pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I need to display only top 10 rows based on total `sum` for each `Class` and order it by Total sum desc. 
This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

So I have my dynamic pivot but I cant understand how to get `total` column for each row and then display only top 10 by `Total` column.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF(
                    (SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([YearMonth]) 
                    FROM #MyTable
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
--print @cols

SELECT @query = 
'
        ;with cte_TopClasses
AS  ( 
        SELECT      
                    CAST(b.MonthNum as varchar(2)) + ''/''+ CAST(b.YearNum as varchar(4)) as YearMonth,
                    b.YearNum,
                    b.MonthNum,
                    GovClassCode + ''- '' + dda.GovClassDesc as Class,
                    ISNULL(SUM(Premium),0) as NetWrittenPremium                 
        FROM        tblCalendar b 
        LEFT JOIN   ProductionReportMetrics prm ON b.YearNum = Year(prm.EffectiveDate) AND b.MonthNum=Month(prm.EffectiveDate) AND  CompanyLine = ''Arch Insurance Company''
        LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[Dynamic_Data_ArchWC] dda ON prm.QuoteGUID = dda.QuoteGuid    
        WHERE       
                    ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
                    ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) )  
                    AND GovClassCode + '' - '' + dda.GovClassDesc IS NOT NULL   
        GROUP BY    b.YearNum ,
                    b.MonthNum, 
                    GovClassCode,   
                    dda.GovClassDesc
    )
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT     
    [YearMonth], 
    Class,
    NetWrittenPremium
FROM cte_TopClasses)X 

PIVOT 
(
    sum(NetWrittenPremium)
    for [YearMonth] in (' + @cols + ')
) P
'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

output from that is 73 rows:

[image]

UPDATE: using `GROUPING SETS`

[image]
UPDATE: This is how data looks before PIVOT:

[image]

Comment: I answered this here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085189/how-to-display-top-10-based-on-total-amount-in-ssrs-2012 You seem to have asked this 4 times. If the answers you get don;t solve your problem then update the question or comment rather than asking it again in a slightly different way.

Comment: I am appreciate your answer but it didn't give me desirable result. I am trying to use dynamic pivot now, and I am stuck with it. I will update the question then. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display top 10 based on total amount in SSRS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085189/how-to-display-top-10-based-on-total-amount-in-ssrs-2012)

Comment: The better question is why are you using a dynamic pivot to do something that SSRS is made for?

Comment: In SSRS I'm able to display top 10, but I am not able to get the sum for only 10. It gives me sum for all records. Thats the only reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF(
                    (SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([YearMonth]) 
                    FROM #MyTable
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') + ',' + '[Total]'
--print @cols

SELECT @query = 
'
        ;with cte_TopClasses
AS  ( 
        SELECT      
                    ISNULL(CAST(b.MonthNum as varchar(2)) + ''/''+ CAST(b.YearNum as varchar(4)), ''Total'') as YearMonth,
                    b.YearNum,
                    b.MonthNum,
                    GovClassCode + ''- '' + dda.GovClassDesc as Class,
                    ISNULL(SUM(Premium),0) as NetWrittenPremium                 
        FROM        tblCalendar b 
        LEFT JOIN   ProductionReportMetrics prm ON b.YearNum = Year(prm.EffectiveDate) AND b.MonthNum=Month(prm.EffectiveDate) AND  CompanyLine = ''Arch Insurance Company''
        LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[Dynamic_Data_ArchWC] dda ON prm.QuoteGUID = dda.QuoteGuid    
        WHERE       
                    ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE())-1 and b.MonthNum >= MONTH(GETDATE())+1 ) OR 
                    ( b.YearNum = YEAR(GETDATE()) and b.MonthNum <= MONTH(GETDATE()) )  
                    AND GovClassCode + '' - '' + dda.GovClassDesc IS NOT NULL   
        GROUP BY    GROUPING SETS
        (
                (
                    b.YearNum ,
                    b.MonthNum, 
                    GovClassCode,   
                    dda.GovClassDesc
                )
                , 
                (
                    GovClassCode
                   ,dda.GovClassDesc
                )
        )
    )
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT     
    [YearMonth], 
    Class,
    NetWrittenPremium
FROM cte_TopClasses)X 

PIVOT 
(
    sum(NetWrittenPremium)
    for [YearMonth] in (' + @cols + ')
) P
'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

The idea is to add the `Total` column in T-SQL using `GROUPING SETS`

Comment: Thanks, but as a result I have only `Total` column with values. For the whole 12 month values are `NULL`s. I posted update

Comment: Could you check the data in the  cte, before the `PIVOT` operator?

Comment: @Oleg Pay attention to that:  in the `YearMonth` before the `pivot` you have values like  month-year (`1/2017`) and after the `pivot` we have columns with names like year-month (`2017/1`), so you need to change how values are calculated or the column names.

Comment: Perfect. Didnt know `GROUPING SETS` can do such awesome tricks. Thank you very much!